# When searching for minimum of a function, how to set minimum change in variables for finite-difference gradients?

Tags: python, optimization

I want to find the minimum of a function in python y = f(x)

Problem : the solver tries to compute the gradient with super close x values (delta x around 1e-8), and my function f is not sensitive to such a small step (ie we can see y vary when delta x around 1e-1).
Hence gradient is 0 to the solver, and can not find the proper solution.

I've tried following solvers from scipy, I can't find the option I'm looking for..

> scipy.optimize.minimize
>
> scipy.optimize.fmin

In Matlab fmincon , there is an option that does the job 'DiffMinChange' : Minimum change in variables for finite-difference gradients (a positive scalar).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try and use L-BFGS-B from scipy:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.html

And provide the “epsilon” parameter to be around 0.1/0.05 and see if it makes it better. I am of course assuming that you will let the solver compute the gradient for you by numerical differentiation (I.e., you pass fprime=None and approx_grad=True) to the routine.

I personally despise the “minimize” interface to various solvers so I prefer to deal with the actual solvers themselves.